# Multiple Outlook.com calendars to Lollipop stock calendar

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calendar, outlook.com

My phone went ballistic yesterday and auto-erased everything and after that I upgraded from 4.4.2. to 5.0.

Now that I should be a happy Lollipop user I've got a huge problem with Outlook.com calendars.

**I've got total of five calendars set up to my @outlook.com -account.** All those calenders synced without a problem with 4.4.2.

Case 1) 
Now with 5.0 when I add new Exchange-account (meaning my Outlook.com) *events from all the calendars are synced into ONE CALENDAR* - not to five separate ones. Also I can only create events to the "Main" calendar.

Case 2)
If I install the official Outlook.com app - all the calendars are visible in the Outlook.com app, but are not synced to the stock calendar.

It's like pre 4.4 again! This issue was fixed for 4.4.2 only and now it's gone again...

**Is there any way to get all the Outlook.com calendars working with the stock calendar?!**

**My corporate Exchange calendar is visible via stock calendar and that is why I want to see our personal Outlook.com calendars in the same calendar... OR if yu can point me an app that does what I want I'd be thrilled!**

Comment: Have you tried exporting all of your exchange calenders to `.ics` format?

Comment: As far as I know .ics-calendars are more static in nature. I need all calendars to be live/editable... Just like before. :) I'm "so close" to reverting back to 4.4.2...

Comment: No, I'm not saying you to use the exported `.ics` file directly. Once you export all the calendar data(s) from your exchange account, you can import it to your google calendar on your computer. Once its is imported you will be able to sync the data to your phone too.

Comment: Other useful/related links [LINK1](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/is-it-possible-to-sync-ms-outlook-with-specific-google-calendar) and [LINK2](http://superuser.com/questions/561660/how-can-i-synchronise-my-outlook-calendar-with-google-calendar-preferably-using)

Comment: did you try google calender app ?